# Condition not satisfying in python

Tags: python

I am having the following problem. Thought the differences are less than 0.0001 the condition is not getting satisfying. I am facing a problem with `abs(beta - beta1).any()` condition.

```
    alpha = -29.18835001947976
    prev_alpha = -29.188337321421681
    beta = np.matrix([[-0.26220145],[ 8.37991712]])
    beta1 = np.matrix([[-0.26220149],[ 8.37991514]])
    print(alpha - prev_alpha)
    print (beta - beta1)
    epsilon = 0.0001
    if ((abs(alpha - prev_alpha) <= epsilon) & (abs(beta - beta1).any() <= epsilon)):
        print 'x'


    print (-1.26980580788e-05 <= 0.001)
True
    print (abs(beta - beta1).all() <0.001)
False
```

Since the condition is not satisfying, the condition is not working. I want to know what can be done to make the 'x' print. I want to get into the condition if all the values in the matrix are almost the same as previous one. If it same, 'x' needs to be printed. I have taken 0.0001 as condition to determine it is almost same. Can anybody help me with this.

Update :

```
    print (any(beta - beta1) <0.001)
False

print(alpha - prev_alpha)
print (beta - beta1)

-1.26980580788e-05
[[  4.00000000e-08]
 [  1.98000000e-06]]
```

Comment: Is this condition satisfied? `(abs(alpha - prev_alpha) <= epsilon)`

Comment: yes, That is why I have kept the condition checking. It comes out as true

Comment: Are you using the `&` operator instead of the `and` operator purposfully?

Comment: What loop? There's no loop in your code.

Comment: @kindall the loop is if loop to print 'x'

Comment: @haimen the if "loop" is a conditional (statement), not really a loop. It's just worth noting so people won't get confused by your wording. :)

Comment: @Jerrybibo oh sorry. My bad..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abs(beta - beta1).any()` is a boolean. If it is True, it is the same as 1, which is always bigger than epsilon.

What you want is probably more like `any(difference < epsilon)`

Comment: My values wont be equal at any time. Some where down the lane some decimal would vary. So only I am having the condition as 0.0001. Can we do anything to check the condition and get into the loop.

Comment: @haimen I think the `any` is misplaced, I edited my answer.

Comment: But still I am getting the same output. I will update the question

Comment: The thing to do is to print all intermediate values: beta, beta - beta1, (beta-beta1).any(), etc. until you understand which one is wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question with all the outputs. All seems to be lower than 0.001 . But still the condition just doesn't pass

Comment: You haven't printed it with `any()`, so you cannot understand why it is wrong. It returns True, which is 1 in Python. You want the all/any outside of the comparison, around it, not inside. Like `all(abs(beta - beta1) <0.001)`